# Service bus QueueClient returns null brokered message even queue has thousands of messages

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

I am using Service Bus Queue to pass items from producer to consumer. Producer is able to successfully send the items to the queue and consumer was receiving correctly but then it is showing weird behavior where receive method returns `null` (with no error) brokered message even if the queue has thousands of message.  What is wrong with my queue?

One thing to mention here is that in testing I called the Close() method on the queue. But it was done only once and while testing. But now every time I run the receive methods return null brokered message.

Comment: Did you attempt to get a message from the queue and hadn't called `Complete` or `Abandon` on it before the `Close`?

Comment: How are you detecting that there are thousands of messages in the queue?

Comment: through queue description and of course through portal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messageCount can include messages from sub-queues such as dead-lettered and scheduled messages. If all your messages have expired then you will have to create a receiver to the dead-lettered subqueue to get them.

Comment: Yes indeed it was the issue. All the queue items are deferred. I tried to recover them by using sequence number(I have to hit for every number from 0 to 10000) but there are still some items unrecovered. Is there any way to recover these deferred items if sequence number is lost?

Comment: Unfortunately at this time there is no way to recover a deferred message if you do not have the sequence number. Brute force receive with numbers upto what you see as the current sequence number would be the alternative.